# How would I refer to a person who says nothing in many words?

Tags: word-request

What would be an appropriate term for a person who says a lot of things but conveys no useful information in saying them? I thought that this is a demagogy, but Wikipedia says that demagogy is proposing popular ideas rather than saying nothing with many words.

**Summarizing the answers:** The discussion here had decided that the answer is *windbag*. However, [the difference between windbag and demagogue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143834) says that demagogue can be more appropriate if zero windbag "argument" successfully attracts the public opinion.

Comment: Your question might be better asked on our [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) site. This isn't really a question about "governments, policies and political processes", per se.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - ELU or ELL? (based on the last couple of podcasts)

Comment: @DVK I believe this is an EL&U question. It's not an "English as a second language" learning issue.

Comment: I think that if someone could give a good answer to that question, than people could make use of that answer in various political discussions.  I think it's a fair question for this site.

Comment: A politician, a sophist, a philosopher, magufo, ...

Basically if there is some _real_ information then that information can be verified, we would be speaking about some kind of science. The lack of falsifiability is common to most (all?) non-science things.

But then we would be speaking about epistemology, which is philosophy, oh no!

While this question may be useful for politics I don't think it is specific for politics. Sorry if my answer was not serious enough, could not help that.

Comment: Shannon's information theory isn't applicable to meaning, by the way.

Comment: Windbag, maybe?

Comment: @StasM is exactly correct. See this definition of [*windbag*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/windbag): *A talkative person who communicates nothing of substance or interest.* Note that it this is a derogatory term. (I don't believe anyone would consider it a compliment to be called a windbag.)

Comment: Windbag, thanks http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/how-would-i-refer-to-a-person-who-says-nothing-in-many-words#comment11763_7389

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A person like this is sometimes referred to as a **windbag**. His talking is just the equivalent of "blowing wind;" that is, not meaningful.

Answer (score 7):

[**Verbose**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbose): using or containing too many words; "long-winded (or windy) speakers"

> Levin smiled joyfully; he was struck by this transition from the
> confused, **verbose** discussion with Pestsov and his brother to this
> laconic, clear, almost wordless communication of the most complex
> ideas.

*Anna Karenina by Tolstoy, Leo*

[**Garrulous**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/garrulous): Given to excessive and often trivial or rambling talk; tiresomely talkative.

> Often, when they had no more agreeable occupation at hand, the Misses
> Murray would amuse themselves with visiting the poor cottagers on
> their father's estate, to receive their flattering homage, or to hear
> the old stories or gossiping news of the **garrulous** old women

*Agnes Grey by Bronte, Anne*

[**Prolix**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prolix): Tediously prolonged; wordy:

> "The manner is indifferent," interrupted Inez, too anxious to await
> the **prolix** explanations of the old man; "why is the visit made?

*The Prairie by Cooper, James Fenimore*

An [**ineffectual**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ineffectual) speaker: Someone whose speech lacks forcefulness or effectiveness; weak

Or more simply a [**bore**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bore): One that is wearingly dull, repetitive, or tedious.

Comment: Won't agree much with *verbose* as it's about using *more words* not necessarily **useless words**. However, +1 for *Garrulous*.

Answer (score 1):

"Blatherer" and "blithering idiot" and "bloviator" are insulting terms for "a person who says nothing in many words".

Sometimes the job of a "diplomat" is to say "nothing in many words".  On the other hand, sometimes the job of a diplomat is to be very clear and to the point.